# How to use two table for users and admins in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I created two table for admins and users,

admins tables:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

users table:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mobile     | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And i created admin model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

And change config in `config/auth.php`:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'user',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

for test, i login in via user, with:

```
$user = User::find(1);
Auth::guard('user')->login($user);
```

it works and i can get user informatin with `Auth::user()`, but when i want login via admins, with:

```
$admin = Admin::find(1);
Auth::guard('admin')->login($admin);
```

I get no error, but user not logged in, how can i fix this?

Comment: Why not just have one table with a `admin` column that's true of false? I don't really see the gain from having them in two different tables?

Comment: i want admin login with email and user login with sms, and some other different, if use one table, users email filed set is null, i think use two table is better way.